# How can I deal with left censoring on continuous outcome variables

Tags: maximum-likelihood, censoring, treatment-effect

I have a Y variable that is long term (ex: profit in the next 12 months). This means that I only fully observe Y only in cohorts that are at least 12 months old, but I can partially observe it in the first cohorts.

How can I estimate a model on this long term outcome variable without discarding the most recent cohorts?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hello: A left censored problem can be changed to a right censored problem by transformation of the time variable. Subtracting all times from the largest time transforms the problem from left censored to right censored. Then it can be treated like a more conventional survival analysis problem.

Good luck!